# Get css id from url

Tags: javascript, css, url

It's probably a silly question but is there a way to get the css id selected from the url?
For example in a url like this:

```
www.website.com#adiv
```

to get `#adiv` using Javascript/jQuery?

**Edit**

My script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var c = window.location.hash;
    $(c).addClass('current');
    $('a').click(function (){
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var c = window.location.hash;
        $(c).addClass('current');
        $('a').click(function () {
            $('.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });
        $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
            && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var $target = $(this.hash);
                $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if ($target.length) {
                    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#header">First</a>
        <a href="#second">Second</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="header">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="history">
        ...
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties)

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(hash).addClass(...);
```

Or directly

```
$(window.location.hash).addClass(...);
```

Comment: How do I select it with jQuery? I've tried with `var c = window.location.hash; c.addClass('blabla');` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `$(window.location.hash).addClass('blabla');` It actually is rather convenient, since by default the "hash" includes the pound sign, so you can feed that right into the jQuery selector.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that it's because you're trying that before the page loads. It has to be done when all elements are loaded, i.e. `$(document).ready(function(){/*blabla*/});`

Comment: @Jeffrey please add additional data to your post, not in the comments.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, edited. It works, when I click, but not when I first load `www.site.com#header` for example.

Comment: @Jeffrey can you post the HTML?

Comment: @Jeffrey what does not work? From the way I see it, the code adds `current` class to the `<section>` with the corresponding `id`.

Comment: In the css `.current` set `color` css property to grey (instead of white) to the text. When I first load the page, the nav list text is all white instead of coloring of grey the first if the url is `www.site.com#header`. When I click on the nav tabs then it color it.

Comment: @Jeffrey try to check using the developer tools of your browser if the class `current` is set on the intended element.

Comment: And I just noticed that when I click it doesn't even update the hash at the end of the url. Maybe that is the problem. How do I update the url with the correct hash?

Comment: @Jeffrey detecting hash changes is done via the [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) event - supported on [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange).

Comment: @Jeffrey tested your code locally, and it works. The class gets appended in the `section` tag with the corresponding `id`.

Comment: @Jeffrey What I meant is that the classes do get appended during pageload. And like I said in the previous comment, you need to add an event handler to the `onhashchange` to detect changes in the hash, for example, when the links are clicked.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, but when I click the link it all works fine a part from the fact that I do not know how to *change* the URL, not how to *detect* the clicking on the link. By the default if you click on the `#generic` link it replace the url with `www.site.com#generic`. When I run my script and click on `#generic` it does not. it remains as it was at the page load.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, the first problem (appending the class at the page load) is fixed, I was considering the wrong element. I mean to append the class to the `a` element, not the `section`. The only problem that remains is when I click on a link it does not change the hash in the url.